# Removing the diff bar in Sublime Text once we have done a git commit

Tags: git, sublimetext3

Sublime Text 3 has the feature that it shows diff markers on the left hand side, like so:

[image: Sublime Text 3 diff marker screenshot from https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/git_integration.html])

My config file is the default, `"git_diff_target": "index"`.

But after I git commit a file, the markers are still there, is there a way to get rid of them? Git should've updated it's index after the commit.

Comment: Not the issue of git index. What's the diff inputs ? Two commits or Head or..  Or how did you get this in sublime ?

Comment: @smilyface Just create some file, add a line, modify a few lines, then delete a line. It shows the same whether it is under git or not. I would it to clear all the markers once I commit the file.

Comment: @smilyface Thanks, the duplicate question indeed fixed it, I just reinstalled the `SideBarEnhancements` extension.

Comment: Oh ok. Hope that worked for you.